# Can anyone verify this story about the President's driver?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, president

I remember hearing a story that I believe was either President Roosevelt or President Truman which involved his driver. There was a crash or incident because of his driver's error or negligence. After the crash the driver was so repentant that he was not fired and continued as his personal driver.

It's also possible that this was a pilot/plane instead of a driver/car.

Can anyone verify whether this is a factual story and point me to where I could find the details if true?

Comment: Are we to believe that, in all other cases, the SOP is that if the President's driver has an accident (which is the driver's fault) they are always fired, regardless of their period of service or overall standard of performance?

Comment: @KillingTime well, I wasn't editorializing on whether they should or should not. Just trying to find an answer if it actually happened.  That said, if my pilot had a history of not checking the fuel or my surgeon left a sponge in me last time then yes I would fire him.  And if they were serving the president of the United States and yes I would expect them to be fired. Though it has nothing to do with the question, expecting a higher standard should be the norm.  The story was actually used as an example of the exemplary service that he provided after-the-fact because he was not fired

Comment: @KillingTime - he might not be fired outright, but he would probably be moved from the list of Presidential drivers...

Comment: Isn't that a backstory from House of Cards?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I believe I may have heard it from Zig Ziglar so I doubt it very seriously

Comment: @KillingTime - I understand that is the SOP for UPS drivers.

Comment: This seems like a better fit for Skeptics SE.

Answer (score 2):

- [Elenor Roosevelt had a car accident](http://docs.fdrlibrary.marist.edu/psf/box23/a903ab01.html),  but she was driving.  She fell asleep at the wheel.
- Maybe unrelated: Franklin Roosevelt had a manservant who he kept even though there were questions about his reliability.  Mrs Roosevelt thought he drank too much.  Reportedly, FDR, who was paralyzed, had a fear of burning in a fire, not being able to escape.  This manservant was kept on staff because it made FDR feel safer having him around even if he wasn't entirely reliable for his daily chores.  I read that in Doris Kearns Goodwin's "No Ordinary Time", about the Roosevelt White House during WWII.
- [President Ford's car was in an accident](https://www.fordlibrarymuseum.gov/library/document/0204/1511873.pdf). As I remember, his driver believed the roads had been closed and thus did not stop at a red light.  I don't believe he was fired.